# hexdump and reading binary files to text

Tags: linux, text, binary, hexdump

Could someone tell me what the fraction for the hexdump command in linux means

```
 hexdump -v -e '7/4 "%010u "' -e '"\n"' binary-file-name
```

I believe it tells hexdump when to stop reading the binary file and start another line? im unsure and i couldnt see an obvious answer in the hexdump manual

Comment: to what you are pointing with your example by "fraction" ?

Comment: after the -e flag there is '7/4... this is the "fraction"

Comment: I mean i know its not actually a fraction it the bottom part has somethig to do with the number of bytes read.. but im not sure what the top part does ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format option includes 3 items:

- **Iteration count:** It is count for how many times format option would be applied
- **Byte count:**        It is count of bytes which would be processed and displayed by hexdump on each iteration of format option applied
- **Format option:**  It is option of hexdump that tells hexdump to display data in this specified format. It is used as “%”

So in your case `7` is the number of iteration counts and `4` the byte count

Comment: Can you write the answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37020333/what-is-iteration-count-and-byte-count-in-hexdump